# How to rebuild entire MySQL data after server re install?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL server running with multiple databases in a 32 bit environment. I need to rebuild my system to a 64 bit environment.

Is it possible to replicate the entire MySQL databases, users, privileges, settings, etc. after the rebuild?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL replication works with mixed hardware architecture
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/replication-faq.html

By default all MySQL databases, users, previleges, settings etc.. unless you specify

> Replicate_Ignore_DB
>
> Replicate_Ignore_Table

option while starting a slave server.